# Sort an object's assocation in Ember.js

Tags: sorting, ember.js

I'm looking to sort an object's association - for instance, I am on a Group (object) page and the Group has many Posts that I show on that page. How would I sort those Posts to arrange them by created_at, or some other property?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `ArrayController` for your collection of `Post`s and then use the built in `sortProperties` and `sortAscending` properties.

```
App.GroupRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController : function(controller,model){
    this._super(controller,model);
    this.controllerFor('posts').set('content',model.get('posts'));
  }
});

App.GroupController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs : ['posts']
}); 

App.PostsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  sortProperties : ['createdAt'],
  sortAscending  : false
});
```

By calling `render` in your group template, you can get access to a controller that has been `need`ed by your main controller. So then your `group` template looks something like this:

```
<h2>Group : {{name}}</h2>
{{ render 'posts' }}
```

And then the `posts` template might be:

```
<ul>
{{#each post in arrangedContent}}
  <li>{{ post.title }}</li>
{{/each}}
</ul>
```

Note that it's using `arrangedContent` as the name of the collection.  You can change the sort order dynamically by `set`ting `sortProperties` and `sortAscending` on `PostsController`.

Here's a JSFiddle of the general idea (but with different model names).

http://jsfiddle.net/YeKCf/

Click on the column headings in the table to see dynamic sorting in action.